# Apache PHP rewrite multiple query string variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am very new to apache and `mod re-write` I am trying to make pretty links using .htaccess. My URL looks like this:

```
http://example.com/single_picture.php?name=Testing-123&cat_id=1
```

I want to make it look like

```
http://example.com/pictures/Testing-123/
```

That is just the name. Here is what I have put in my `.htaccess` file but it is not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^pictures/(\s+)*$ ./single_picture.php?name=$1&cat_id=$2
```

How do I do it?
Ahmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^pictures/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /single_picture.php?name=$1&cat_id=$2
```

Also remember that a rewrite will not rewrite the request a user has made. i.e. `http://example.com/single_picture.php?name=Testing-123&cat_id=1` will work as will `http://example.com/pictures/Testing-123/1/`.

You will need to make the user view the page via the SEO link by changing the links on your website to reflect this.

Comment: Michael thanks for your answer. I replaced the code in my .htaccess with the one you provided but unfortunately it is not working as I expect. For example here is the working url http://www.unclelol.com/single_picture.php?name=Geo-news%20&&%20cat_id=1  but when I enter http://www.unclelol.com/pictures/Geo-news/1/ it doesn't

Comment: Ok, this is not an issue with your .htaccess file. It is with the association to your css and js files in the `<head>` section of your website. I like to work from the root of my site when adding css and js link. So, to steal a bit of code from your website `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`, simply change it to `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` (Notice the leading slash). This tells the browser to start at the roor of the websites filesystem.

Comment: @AhmarAli Just another note. Don't forget to also apply this same rule to your images. `/` in front.

Comment: You have been great so far. Can you please tell me how do I make the format look like picture/category/and then picture name?

Comment: Ok, first some extra readin (for extra credit on the test) [link](http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/) Next, to summarise that article, lets look at the line of code i gave you.
`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` is simply like a regular expression, it tells apache to look for (almost) every character. `$1` tell apache to use the first of the regular expressions as a variable. `$2` tells apache to use the second of the regular expression as the variable.

Comment: @AhmarAli I think this is what you were wanting. `RewriteRule ^picture/category-([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /single_picture.php?cat_id=$1&name=$2` This will make `http://example.com/picture/category-1/Testing-123/`